# How Higgs Field is a constant in an Expanding Universe

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, higgs, physical-constants

Going through information on Higgs Field in various forums, it seems that the mass of an object is due its interaction with the Higgs Field which is  constant throughout the universe.

However it fails to provide reasons of how and why  the field could be constant over time from the big bang, given that the universe has expanded and continues to do so.

A reasonably non-mathematical answer which could satisfy the observations  would be appreciated.

Comment: Why does the constancy of the field (I assume you're talking about its vacuum expectation value) need a particular reason to be valid during expansion?

Comment: The constant quantity is the vacuum expectation value of the Higgs field. This, along with the Yukawa couplings, determines the fermion masses. Can you extend your question to explain why the VEV of the Higgs field should change in an expanding universe? It is not at all obvious to me why you think this should be the case.

Comment: @JohnRennie, maybe you could post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @heather: I'm not sure the question can be answered at the moment. It asks why the Higgs VEV is constant when the answer is *because it's constant*. I think the question needs to provide more detail about **why** we might expect it not to be constant.

Comment: @JohnRennie, I see; my mistake.

Comment: @heather: if this is something you're interested in [Matt Strassler has written a really good introductory article on it here](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/how-the-higgs-field-works-with-math/1-the-basic-idea/).

Comment: The OP has an intuitive view on the matter and he probably thinks that the Higgs VeV is some like an energy density, and thus it should decrease with the expansion of the Universe. On my opinion a good answer should only show that these are independent.